# Create-react-app couldn't generate and has errors

Tags: reactjs, macos, sudo

I haven't code for a while and want to get back into it. When I tried to run: npx create-react-app my-app,  this is what returned to me:

`Creating a new React app in /Users/kyhongle/Desktop/my-app.`

`Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.`

`Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...`

`npm ERR! code EACCES`

`npm ERR! syscall mkdir`

`npm ERR! path /Users/kyhongle/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/0b/62`

`npm ERR! errno -13`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in`

`npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:`

`npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/kyhongle/.npm"`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`

`npm ERR!     /Users/kyhongle/.npm/_logs/2020-03-18T21_14_29_829Z-debug.log`

`Aborting installation.`

`npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.`

`Deleting generated file... package.json`

`Deleting my-app/ from /Users/kyhongle/Desktop`

`Done.`

I am not sure how to go from here. Before that I did something, probably shouldn't have, I ran a sudo npm cache clean -f. I think that could have been what causing this problem. If someone can help me reverse this, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution? 
"To permanently fix this problem, please run:
 sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/kyhongle/.npm"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your trace:

> npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
>
> npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/kyhongle/.npm"

```sh
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/kyhongle/.npm"
```

And I'm pretty sure you don't need to run `npm cache clean -f` as `sudo`, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The code EACCES is a permissions error code.

First you can try `sudo npx create-react-app my-app`.

Or in your stacktrace, try running `sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/kyhongle/.npm"` to recursively change the owner of the directory and it's files.